# Batch file to backup data to networked drive?

Tags: windows, batch-file, network-programming, backup, xcopy

I am trying to create a backup of some local files on one machine, to a networked hard drive on another machine. The source computer is running Windows Server 2008 R2, and the destination machine is running Windows Server 2003 R2. I want to create a batch file that will run on the source computer, and copy all of the files in the D:\MICROS folder to a separate network drive. \marketing\TeraByte\marketingdata\MICROS\TESTBKUP\ is where the files will need to end up. The batch file will be executed through the task scheduler, and should run regardless of whether or not a user is logged in. I tried to make the batch file myself, and this was the best I could come up with

```
rem 05.21.2014 - script to Backup the 1 TB drive attached to marketing server.
rem - use program to determine day of wek - then use the DAY of THE WEEK as the sub dir name
set y =%date:~-4,4%
set m =%date:~-10,2%
set d =%date:~-7,2%
set today = %y%%m%%d%
set DOW=%1
echo on
echo DOW
net use M: /D
net use M: \\marketing\TeraByte\marketingdata\
xCopy D:\MICROS\*.*       M:\MICROS\TESTBKUP\            /CDEFHIY > M:\MICROS\BU%today%MICROS%DOW%.TXT
echo Yes, the task really did execute >> \\marketing\TeraByte\MarketingData\MICROS\TESTBKUP\testlog.txt\
pause
:end
```

The stuff at the beginning is just used to generate a date, and that was all copy/pasted from a script my boss had already created. Where my code starts is after the "echo DOW" line. Whenever I try to get this to run, the task scheduler returns an operational code 2, and says the operation successfully completed, but none of the files were actually copied.

What really confuses me about this whole thing, is that even though this script doesn't work, despite mapping the drive and using UNC paths, is that the following script created by my boss never mentions any network locations, yet it runs flawlessly and backs up the files to exactly the correct network drive. The Z: drive isn't even mapped on the server that script runs on, and yet it somehow knows it needs to go over the network.:

```
rem
rem 04.09.2010 - script to Backup to 4 Terabyte drive attached to Stephs new windows 7 64bit PC
rem - use program to determine day of week - then use the DAY of THE WEEK as the sub dir name
REM 5.25.10 add RevAcctg and exclusion directories
set y=%date:~-4,4%
set m=%date:~-10,2%
set d=%date:~-7,2%
set today=%y%%m%%d%
set DOW=%1
echo on
echo dow
xCopy  \\MArketing2\AlysonAvino\*.*     Z:\backup\AlysonAvini\%DOW%\        /CDEFHIY >  Z:\BU%today%Alyson%DOW%.TXT
rem goto end
xCopy  D:\DiskImage\*.*        V:\backup\DiskImage\               /CDEFHIY >  V:\BU%today%DiskImage%DOW%.TXT
xCopy  D:\MarkWolf\*.*         Z:\backup\MarkWolf\%DOW%\          /CDEFHIY >  Z:\BU%today%MarkWolf%DOW%.TXT
xcopy  \\otbdata\greatPlains\Bill  Z:\Backup\Bill\%DOW%\          /CDEFHIY >  Z:\BU%today%Bill%DOW%.txt
xcopy  \\otbdata\greatPlains\MSDynamicsGP\FrxServer  Z:\Backup\FrxServer\%DOW%\            /CDEFHIY >  Z:\BU%today%FrxServer%DOW%.txt
xcopy  \\otbdata\greatPlains\CrystalReports  Z:\Backup\CrystalReports\BU%today%\  /CDEFHIY >  Z:\BU%today%Crystal%DOW%.txt
xcopy  \\otbdata\greatPlains\RevAcctG  Z:\Backup\RevAcctG\BU%today%\  /CDEFHIY >  Z:\BU%today%RevAcctG%DOW%.txt
xcopy  D:\administration\*.*  Z:\BACKUP\ADMINISTRATION\%DOW%\     /CDEFHIY >  Z:\BU%today%ADMIN%DOW%.TXT
xcopy  D:\accounting\*.*      Z:\backup\ACCOUNTING\%DOW%\         /CDEFHIY >  Z:\BU%today%ACCT%DOW%.TXT
xCopy  D:\HR\*.*              Z:\backup\HR\%DOW%\                 /CDEFHIY >  Z:\BU%today%HR%DOW%.TXT
xcopy  F:\marketingdata\*.*   Z:\backup\MARKETING\%DOW%\          /CDEFHIY >  Z:\BU%today%MRKT%DOW%.TXT
xcopy  D:\surveillance\*.*    Z:\backup\Surveillence\%DOW%\       /CDEFHIY >  Z:\BU%today%Surv%DOW%.TXT
xCopy  D:\CD\*.*              Z:\backup\CD\%DOW%\                 /CDEFHIY >  Z:\BU%today%CD.TXT
xCopy  C:\Maintenance\*.*     Z:\backup\Maint\%DOW%\              /CDEFHIY >  Z:\BU%today%Maint%DOW%.TXT
xCopy  D:\Schedule\*.*        Z:\backup\Schedule\%DOW%\           /CDEFHIY >  Z:\BU%today%Schedule%DOW%.TXT
xCopy  D:\printshop\*.*       Z:\backup\printshop\%DOW%\          /CDEFHIY >  Z:\BU%today%printshop%DOW%.TXT
xCopy  F:\Exclusion\*.*       Z:\backup\Exclusion\%DOW%\          /CDEFHIY >  Z:\BU%today%Exclusion%DOW%.TXT
xCopy  F:\GAMING\*.*          Z:\backup\GAMING\%DOW%\             /CDEFHIY >  Z:\BU%today%GAMING%DOW%.TXT
xCopy  F:\LUBA\*.*            Z:\backup\SrvrLUBA\%DOW%\           /CDEFHIY >  Z:\BU%today%SrvrLuba%DOW%.TXT
xCopy  F:\AdamSecured\*.*     Z:\backup\AdamSecured\%DOW%\        /CDEFHIY >  Z:\BU%today%AdamSecured%DOW%.TXT
xCopy  D:\DOWNLOADS\*.*       Z:\backup\DOWNLOADS\%DOW%\          /CDEFHIY >  Z:\BU%today%DOWNLOADS%DOW%.TXT
xCopy  F:\MartyFiles\*.*      Z:\backup\MartyFiles\%DOW%\         /CDEFHIY >  Z:\BU%today%MartyFiles%DOW%.TXT
xCopy  F:\LUBAold\*.*         Z:\backup\LUBAold\%DOW%\            /CDEFHIY >  Z:\BU%today%LUBAold%DOW%.TXT
xCopy  D:\TestSecurity\*.*    Z:\backup\TestSecurity\%DOW%\       /CDEFHIY >  Z:\BU%today%TestSecurity%DOW%.TXT
:end
rem do this on mkt2 server XCOPY  G:\*.*    Z:\BACKUP\CreativeGraphics\%DOW%\   /CDEFHIY   > Z:\BU%Today%CreativeGraphics%DOW%.TXT
```

I've been working on this for days and have had no success. I've tried every possible fix I could think of, and trawled the internet for answers, but to no avail.

Comment: have you tried any of those statements by themselves In the command prompt?   like `xCopy  \\MArketing2\AlysonAvino\*.*     Z:\backup\AlysonAvini\%DOW%\        /CDEFHIY >  Z:\BU%today%Alyson%DOW%.TXT`

Comment: I just tried, that and it gives the error "The system cannot find the path specified". I honestly have no idea how his script manages to run. It defies all logic.

Comment: do you have `Z:` Drive mapped? What OS are you running this on?

Comment: No, the Z: drive is not mapped. The second script, the one my boss created that runs fine, runs on the windows server 2003 R2 machine. It runs every night via the task scheduler, and it always works without issue. However, attempting to input those xCopy commands into the comand prompt gives an error. That is why I have no idea how that script manages to run.

Comment: Try `dir Z:\backup\AlysonAvini` and also dir \\MArketing2\AlysonAvino\ from a cmd prompt.

Answer (score 3):

use this it will work:

```
net use z: \\SERVER\d$ /user:<Username> <Password>
xcopy Z:\test\*.* e:\xcopy /j /v /y >> e:\backup_log.txt
```

Windows scheduler cannot see user map drives so i am creating map drive alias in the code using "net use" command and after that we can use xcopy command with the newly created alias and sending the out put of the xcopy command to "e:\backup_log.txt" file

Comment: Hope this will help i have explained it and keep it simple so anyone can implement it.